# Relation between gradient of a function with respect two linear connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $\bar{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ be two linear connection over $(M,\bar{g})$ and $(M,g)$ resp. and suppose that this two connection are related by the following equality:
$$\bar{\nabla}_XY=\nabla_XY+\psi(X,Y),\qquad \forall\, X,Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M),$$
where $\psi$ is a given $(2,1)$-tensor field. Let $f$ be a smooth function on $M$. Then How $\bar{\nabla}f$ and $\nabla f$ are related (and then their Hessians)?

**My attempt:**
$$\bar{\nabla} (fY)=(\bar{\nabla} f)Y+f\bar{\nabla}Y=(\bar{\nabla} f)Y+f\nabla Y+f\psi(.,Y),$$
$$\bar{\nabla}(f Y)=\nabla(fY)+\psi(., fY)=(\nabla f)Y+f\nabla Y+f\psi(.,Y),$$
So $(\nabla f)Y=(\bar{\nabla} f)Y$ for all $Y$. Thus $\bar{\nabla}f=\nabla f$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. For any connection $\nabla$, the covariant derivative of a scalar function satisfies $\nabla f = df$, so it doesn't depend on the connection. The connection only makes a difference when you take covariant derivatives of vector or tensor fields.

Comment: I asked this question because of definition of $grad f$ in your book (p. 28) depend on the metric; i.e $df (Y)=\left< grad\, f,Y\right>$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I see. Yes the gradient does depend on the metric. But $\nabla f$ is not the gradient -- it's the total covariant derivative, which in the case of a function is the same as $df$.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of Hessian:
$${\rm Hess}\, f(X,Y)=X.(df(Y))-df(\nabla_XY),$$
we have
\begin{align}\overline{{\rm Hess}}\, f(X,Y)=X.(df(Y))-df(\bar{\nabla}_XY)&=X.(df(Y))-df(\nabla_XY+\psi(X,Y))\\
&={\rm Hess}\, f(X,Y)-df(\psi(X,Y)).
\end{align}